# Call 2 post controller methods on single form submission in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model-view-controller, form-submit

I have a use case where I need to create 2 tuples ( one in Invitation and one in Notification table) on single form submission( action is directed to Invitation#create).
How do I call the Notification create method from Invitation create to create a new tuple in  Notification table.

PS: No relation between Invitation and Notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't go to the notifications create action, you would just do it in the Invitation create. The below code will use a shared concern method, explained below it:

```
class InvitationsController < ApplicationController
    include Notifications

    #....

    def create
        invitation = Invitiation.create(invitation_params)
        create_notification(invitation)
    end

    private

    def invitation_params
        # strong params code
    end
end
```

So if you had a second controller/model, e.g Rsvp:

```
class RsvpsController < ApplicationController
    include Notifications

    #....

    def create
        rsvp = Rsvp.create(rsvp_params)
        create_notification(rsvp)
    end

    private

    def rsvp_params
        # strong params code
    end
end
```

Then in controllers/concerns directory, you could create a file 'notifications.rb'

```
module Notifications
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def create_notification(object)
    Notification.create(object_id: object.id, object_type: object_type)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you and Yes that would used in multiple controllers.So, that create method would be in Notification controller ? and Do I need a route for that ? If possible could you give me a small snippet.

Comment: No there would be no second route, the form would post to Invitations create and in there you would directly create the Notification via the model method. You would never go to two controller actions from a post.

Comment: When I said multiple controllers, I meant if you need to create a Notification across multiple controllers - for example if you had Invitation and Rsvp models/controllers, and both of them needed a notification, you could create a shared method that can be used in those two controllers. That method would create the notification directly via the model.

Comment: If using a concern, you'll need to include it in your controller.`include Notifications`

Comment: Whoops, you're right of course, thanks. I've updated my answer.